# How To Copy Values To Object Array

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a class with a few objects.

```
class SalesPerson {
    String number;
    String name;
    double salesAmount;
}
```

So now I need to copy some data from a text file to an array. 

**"sales.txt"**

```
S0001
Alice
2000
S0002
Bob
3400
S0003
Cindy
1200
S0004
Dave
2600
```

Below is the shortened version of my code, assuming that the getName(s), setName(s) and constructors are created and the text file can be successfully read:

```
class ArrayImport {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = "sales.txt";
        SalesPerson sp = new SalesPerson[4]; //Manually counted

        //Read the file
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));

        //Copy data to array
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sp[i].name = sc.nextLine(); //Error starts here
            sp[i].number = sc.nextLine();
            sp[i].salesAmount = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException..." pointing to the line which I commented "Error starts here".

So I am guessing that this is not the way to assign a value to an object array, and if my guess is correct, what are the correct syntax?

Comment: You haven't created any instances of `SalesPerson`. All you're missing is `staff[i] = new SalesPerson();` before you start assigning to individual fields. (I'd personally write a `SalesPerson` constructor accepting three parameters, but that's a different matter. I'd also use `BigDecimal` for currency values rather than `double`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of object is null so you have to create the instance first. so create instance like this 'staff[i] = new SalesPerson();'
I added instance creation to your code.

```
  class ArrayImport {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = "sales.txt";
        SalesPerson sp = new SalesPerson[4]; //Manually counted

        //Read the file
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));

        //Copy data to array
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            staff[i] = new SalesPerson();
            staff[i].name = sc.nextLine(); //Error starts here
            staff[i].number = sc.nextLine();
            staff[i].salesAmount = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to change "staff" to "sp". I wanted it to be shorter so it's easier to read in the thread, I thought. 
Anyway, I tried your way to create an instance of the object but got a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error instead, it points to the line where the instance of object is created.

Comment: Indexed outof boub except is your array length is not enough so change the array size to larger amount. Current is 4

Comment: Well, it turns out to be that I've forgotten my actual sales.txt file has more than just those records. I kinda want to make it short here but ended up confusing myself. Your method actually worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
public class ArrayImport {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            List<SalesPerson> persons = new ArrayList<>();
            SalesPerson salesPerson = null; //Manually counted

            //Read the file
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("sales.txt"));

            int count=0;
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                if( count==0 || count%3 == 0) {
                    salesPerson = new SalesPerson();
                    salesPerson.setNumber(scanner.nextLine());
                    salesPerson.setName(scanner.nextLine());
                    salesPerson.setSalesAmount(Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine()));
                    persons.add(salesPerson);
                    count+=3;
                }
            }
            persons.forEach(person->System.out.println(person.toString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is runnable and but the printed lines are quite weird. 
For each information of the 'persons' printed, the output are like this "SalesPerson@1b28cdfa". 
I tried System.out.println(salesPerson.name) and actually got something, it is confirmed that the data are being copied, just that they're not displaying when printed using forEach.